# How can I touch up the paint on crown molding where I inadvertently applied wall paint?

Tags: painting, trim, finishing

I've painted the drywall and even though I carefully put the paint tape around the ceiling molding, I still made some marks on it. So I tried to remove it after with a damp/wet cloth, it didn't help though.

The molding is white colored, so I guess I don't need to repaint it all together but just touch it. Am I right?

Can I just dip a piece of cloth in a well stirred paint and then simply buff it over the marked spots on the moldings?

I'm newbie :-)

Thanks for feedback!

[image]

Comment: A picture of the problem would help understanding.

Comment: @RobElliott, I updated the post.

Comment: You might try a latext paint solvent (Goof Off is an example). Lightly dampen a cloth and gently buff. It might take off just the newer paint.

Comment: Try denatured alcohol. Dampen a cloth and buff. The existing will be fine. This also works for removing paint goofs on stained trim.

Comment: If you touch up the molding, you might be back here asking how to get white paint off a green wall!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just take a small brush, pour a bit of paint in a plastic cup and go along and touch it up. Make sure to wipe off the brush very well, so only a little paint is applied and you reduce the chance of drips.

Another positive you have going for you is this is up high so people aren't going to be looking at it too closely.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a small amount of dish soap (I prefer Blue Dawn) and one of those mildly abrasive kitchen dish scrubbers. It will probably come right off.